# Posting lots of checkboxes

Tags: php, html, post, http-post

**UPDATE 2:**

The following gives me `UDPATE table SET db_field1=0, dbfield2=0, dbfield3=0, dbfield4=0 WHERE 1=1` no matter which options are checked:

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {

        $fields = array('db_field1'=>'cb1', 'dbfield2'=>'cb2', 'dbfield3'=>'cb3', 'dbfield4'=>'cb4');

        $update = '';

        foreach($fields as $dbfield => $field) {
            if ($update) $update.= ',';

            $update.= ' '.$dbfield.'=';

            if (isset($_POST[field])) {
                $update.= 1;
            } else {
                $update.= 0;
            }
        }

        echo 'UDPATE table SET'.$update.' WHERE 1=1';

    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb2" />
            <!-- all the way to 50 -->
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb3" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb4" />

            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {

        if( isset( $_POST["cb"] ) ) {

            $update = "";

            foreach ($_POST['cb'] as $key => $value) {

                if ( $update ) $update.= ', ';

                $update .= $key . " = 1";

            }

            echo "update table1 set " . $update . " where uid = 10";

        }

    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb[col1]" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb[col2]" />
            <!-- all the way to 50 -->
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb[col3]" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb[col4]" />

            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have a PHP form with lots of checkboxes to allow users to select which options to turn on or off.

What is the best way to return which checkboxes are checked so I can insert the data into the database as either 0's or 1's?

I have the following code, but this seems a bit excessive if I used this method for all 50 checkboxes:

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
        if( isset( $_POST["cb1"] ) ) {
            // insert 1 in relevant database table cell
            echo 1;         
        } else {
            // insert 0 in relevant database table cell
            echo 0;
        }

        if( isset( $_POST["cb2"] ) ) {
            // insert 1 in relevant database table cell
            echo 1;         
        } else {
            // insert 0 in relevant database table cell
            echo 0;
        }

        // all the way to 50

        if( isset( $_POST["cb49"] ) ) {
            // insert 1 in relevant database table cell
            echo 1;         
        } else {
            // insert 0 in relevant database table cell
            echo 0;
        }

        if( isset( $_POST["cb50"] ) ) {
            // insert 1 in relevant database table cell
            echo 1;         
        } else {
            // insert 0 in relevant database table cell
            echo 0;
        }
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb2" />
            <!-- all the way to 50 -->
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb49" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb50" />

            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array with all the different fields:

```
$fields = array('db_field1'=>'cb1', 'dbfield2'=>'cb2', 'dbfield3'=>'etc', );

$update = '';

foreach($fields as $dbfield => $field) {
    if ($update) $update.= ',';

    $update.= ' '.$dbfield.'=';

    if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
      $update.= 1;
    } else {
      $update.= 0;
    }
}

$query = 'UDPATE table SET'.$update.' WHERE 1=1';
```

Where db_field is the name of the column in the table and cd are the html field names

**EDIT**

Added better sample code

**EDIT 2**

Fixed post variable

Comment: I am a little confused as to how to link this with the checkboxes which are checked and those which are not checked?

Comment: @oshirowanen: That's just me being an idiot and trying to type :) `$_POST[field]` should be `$_POST[$field]`. And the `where 1=1` was just an example where statement which you should replace with the correct one

Comment: @oshirowaren: Great. You're welcome. Sorry for the confusion :)

Answer (score 2):

Define a map between the checkbox name (POST array entry name) and the mysql table name; use that to construct your SQL to do the value insertion.

Comment: Please see update 1.  I am trying to map the checkbox names with the database column names, but am not sure how to deal with the options which are not selected or de-selected?  Also, won't this allow sql-injections?

Comment: @oshirowanen: you don't have to worry about sql injection when you set the value based on wether the variables are set or not.

Answer (score 1):

in HTML do the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxeslist[1]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxeslist[2]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxeslist[49]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxeslist[50]" />
```

in PHP do the following:

```
<?php
     if (isset($_POST['checkboxeslist'])) {
          //one is at least selected; hence start looping
          foreach ($_POST['checkboxeslist'] as $key => $value) {
               echo $key; //this will print 1,2,49,50 etc... ONLY IF they have been selected
               //do the DB call here
          }
     }
?>
```

In order to also get the non selected checkboxes do the following (only if you want all the numbers between 1 & 50:

```
<?php
     if (isset($_POST['checkboxeslist'])) {
          //one is at least selected; hence start looping
          for ($i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++) {
               if (isset($_POST['checkboxeslist'][$i])) {
                   echo "1";
               } else {
                   echo "0";
               }
          }
     }
?>
```

Comment: How do I set the 0's for the options which are not selected or de-selected?

Answer (score 0):

For HTML, you can just loop through those fields too. Have a list of the columns somewhere; with MVC model you could take them from model. Otherwise an array would suffice, or querying database about contents of the table.

For taking column names from database:

```
 SELECT name FROM syscolumns 
 WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM sysobjects 
 WHERE name= 'MyTableName') 
 ORDER by colorder
```

Then,

```
foreach($columns as $column) {
     echo '<input type="text" name="cb['. $column .']" />' . "\n";
}
```

to print the columns.